# how to get Value that cause exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the value that failed to be converted? In general, and not in this single specific example case.

```
try
{
    textBox1.Text = "abc";
    int id = Convert.ToInt(textBox1.Text);
}
catch
{
    // Somehow get the value for the parameter to the .ToInt method here 
}
```

Comment: Value for *cause exception* ?

Comment: I think he means try catch throw..

Comment: `I think he means ...` That is the problem with the question...

Comment: I am not sure about you question but you can handle for using `int.TryParse`

Comment: the question is (I believe): how can I get the value that was failed to be converted ? In general, and not in this single specific case.

Comment: Tigran understand my problem. I need to get the value that failded to be converted.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this?

```
int id;
if(int.TryParse(textbox.Text, out id)
{
   //Do something
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(textbox.Text);
}
```

You can also use as earlier suggestet a try catch to catch a exception and show the textbox.Text in the catch.

EDIT : (After question changed direction)
To show the value that was unable to convert you can do as following.

```
string myValue = "some text";
int id = 0;
try
{
   id = Convert.ToInt32(myValue);
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Unable to convert {0} to int", myValue));
}
```

Comment: @NomanNasir, i've updated my answer now according to what i think you are after... (stumbling in the dark)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching an exception which is more expensive, use int.TryParse(). TryParse returns a boolean specifying whether the conversion failed or succeeded. It also returns as an output parameter the converted value.

```
int result = 0; 
string input = "abc";
if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
{
   //Converted value is in  out parameter
}
else
{
   //Handle invalid input here
}
```

Comment: Yes, exceptions are (relatively) expensive, but you only take the expense if the exception is actually generated and thrown.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. That's why it's bad practice to use exceptions for logic.

Comment: I need to get the value that failded to be converted.in catch section

Comment: You have the original value already. It doesn't need to be in an Exception block if all you're trying to do is parse. It's up to you what to use, but I prefer TryParse

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
int i = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse (textbox.Text, out i)) 
{
    // i is good here
}
else 
{
    // i is BAD here, do something about it, like displaying a validation message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.Text = "abc";
try
{      
  int id = Convert.ToInt(textBox1.Text);
}
catch(FormatException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
}
```